# Storing google maps polygons in mysql

Tags: mysql, maps, polygons

I want to draw polygons in google maps and for these to be stored in mysql. I then want to be able to upload polylines and see if they intersect with the polygons. Is this possible?

Comment: You're asking two separate questions:  1.  Can one store google maps polygons in a database? 2. Can I see if a polyline intersects a polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do it with google maps, but you can use leaflet and openstreetmaps to develop it.
Using leaflet you can draw polygon and get that value in a textbox and save it in your database.
http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

Try this example
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw